# HAProxy validation fails because of hard-coded file paths

Tags: haproxy

I've got hard-coded file paths in my HAProxy config:

```
defaults
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http

frontend https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.example.com.cer
```

I'd like to validate the file in a Docker container (to do it locally or in the CI/CD pipeline). However, both files can't be found:

> haproxy@56dad58e757b:/usr/src/app$ haproxy -f my_config.cfg -c
> [NOTICE]   (32) : haproxy version is 2.6.5-987a4e2
> [NOTICE]   (32) : path to executable is /usr/local/sbin/haproxy
> [ALERT]    (32) : config : parsing [my_config.cfg:38] : errorfile : error opening file '/etc/haproxy/errors/400.http'.
> [ALERT]    (32) : config : parsing [my_config.cfg:93] : 'bind *:443' in section 'frontend' : unable to stat SSL certificate from file '/etc/ssl/private/wildcard.example.com.cer' : No such file or directory.

`/etc/haproxy/errors/400.http` is correct when running HAProxy under Ubuntu. But it cannot be found here because the HAProxy config path is `/usr/local/etc/haproxy` in the [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy).

1.) Is there a variable that points to HAProxy's config directory, so one could write something like this?

```
defaults
    errorfile 400 $CONF_DIR/errors/400.http
```

The second problem is the missing certificate (`/etc/ssl/private/wildcard.example.com.cer`). Obviously I don't want to store it on my local machine.

2.) Is there a way to "fake" the certifcate file to make the validation pass?

Comment: (1) Can you just `ln -s /usr/local/etc/haproxy /etc/haproxy` in the container before running your validation script? (2) You can trivially generate an ssl certificate with something like `openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -sha256 -days 365 -subj "/CN=example"`

Comment: "Obviously I don't want to store it on my local machine." Why not? It's worth remembering that *certificates* are public keys: anybody who visits your website can download your certificate.

Comment: Thank you, linking the directory and creating a certificate work!